# Sender sometimes send wrong value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have `UICollectionView` with custom flow layout, which purpose is availability to delete items. In order to retrieve index i use function:

```
-(void)aMethod:(UIButton*)sender{
    [self.viewModel deleteAt:[sender tag]];
    [self.myCollectionView reloadData];
}
```

Sometimes (in rare cases) i got crash. When i dig into it, i found that sometimes `[sender tag]` was incorrect, in fact, higher then array of items count. Why is that happen? I found that it send 8, when array only had 5 items.

Button is simple 40x40 width/height image, placed above UITableViewCell like this:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton new];
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"m_delete"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        if (self.shouldEdit){

            self.layout.longPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.3f;
            NSLog(@"1 blk called");
        [button addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(aMethod:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setTag:indexPath.row];
        [cell addSubview:button];

        [button mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {

            make.left.equalTo(cell.mas_left).with.offset(2);
            make.top.equalTo(cell.mas_top).with.offset(2);

        }];

        }
```

Comment: I believe you've answered your own question. As you said, the purpose you used for the tag was to delete items. However, a tag remains static, unless you change it. So, let's say you had 8 items, with index 0 - 7, and therefore tags 0 - 7. Then you delete the first item in the list. Now you have 7 items,  with indices 0 - 6. BUT you deleted the button with tag of 0, and the remaining button tags still are numbered 1 - 7. A tag of 7 with your new, smaller array of 6 items, is too large.

So, don't delete based off a fixed index tag. Delete based off the index of the button in the collection.

Comment: @christopherdrum well, in that case i will get crash every time, but it happens in really rare occasions. Thank you for answer though

Comment: No, you won't get a crash every time. It will depend on the order you delete things in. If you delete in reverse order, bottom to top, it probably won't crash at all.

Comment: @christopherdrum okay, how exactly should i set correct tag?

Comment: I think I'm not making myself clear. Using the tag as an index for deletion is inappropriate, because the tags are probably not being reset to reflect the new array (probably because of cell reuse, automatically done by the system for performance reasons). Instead, find the cell that contains the button, find the index of that cell, and use the cell's index to make the deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that it's reusing old cell without updating the button's tag. Since you have conditions `if (self.shouldEdit)` which means the `[button setTag:indexPath.row];` is not always called. You mentioned that the purpose of the buttons is to delete items so it might be that the tableView reused old / deleted cell (the one with tag 8) as one of the 5 cells and it doesn't call the setTag

You can take the setTag line outside the conditional so it will always update the button's tag every time the cell is created / reused.

Alternatively you can make sure the old button are removed from cell before reuse in UITableViewCell's `prepareForReuse` or inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` right after `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(...)`. Doing this you must always add new button because the old ones are removed from the cell

Answer (score 0):

button tag is override every time when cellForRowAtIndexPath callled  so dont set tag in that method
remove this line

```
[button setTag:indexPath.row];
```

use this one

```
-(void)aMethod:(UIButton*)sender
{
    CGPoint point=[sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:collectiewname];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath=[collectiewname indexPathForItemAtPoint:point];
   NSLog(@"row :%ld",(long)indexPath.row)


}
```

Comment: in a moment please.

Comment: problem is, i create UIButtons and delete it after ifEdit condition is false (user enter that condition when he long press button). Therefore using single button reference is not work in my case..

Comment: you have need to add  uibutton in cell if ifEdit condition is false so you can get right tag means you need to add uibutton every time